# Changing the texture in a Sprite

Tags: libgdx

I'm a bit new to libGDX. My problem is ,in my code, only if I set the texture in the constructor of the Sprite instance, it will draw anything. My question is shouldn't it be working when I only call setTexture() when rendering? Or is there another way to render while changing the texture?

Following code doesn't draw anything.

```
public Sprite getSprite() {
    if (this.sprite == null) {
        this.sprite = new Sprite();
    }
    return this.sprite;
}

public void render(final float deltaTime, final SpriteBatch batch) {
    this.getSprite().setTexture(this.getCurrentTexture());
    this.getSprite()
            .setPosition(this.getPosition().x, this.getPosition().y);
    this.getSprite().setRotation(this.getRotation());
    this.getSprite().draw(batch);
}
```

Following is the working code.

```
public Sprite getSprite() {
    if (this.sprite == null) {
        this.sprite = new Sprite(this.getCurrentTexture());
    }
    return this.sprite;
}

public void render(final float deltaTime, final SpriteBatch batch) {
    this.getSprite().setTexture(this.getCurrentTexture());
    this.getSprite()
            .setPosition(this.getPosition().x, this.getPosition().y);
    this.getSprite().setRotation(this.getRotation());
    this.getSprite().draw(batch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SpriteBatch` has to be started before you can use it. First use:

```
batch.begin()
```

And at the end use:

```
batch.end()
```

Comment: ty for the edit